# stop drag of text object within boundary on canvas

Tags: drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I want to move my text object within a rectangle on canvas using easeljs. I would like the text object to stop moving as soon as it touches the rectangle boundary. How can I do this in easeljs? Or is better using another framework? Or layered canvases?

My rectangle boundary on the canvas loos like this:

```
var textBoundary = new createjs.Shape();
 textBoundary.graphics.beginStroke("#999");
 textBoundary.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1);
 textBoundary.snapToPixel = true;
 textBoundary.graphics.drawRect(82, 130, 149, 240);
 textBoundary.setBounds(82, 130, 149, 240);
 stage.addChild(textBoundary);

stage.update();
```

My dragger code looks like this until now:

```
var textFront = new createjs.Text();
var t = document.getElementById("TextInput1").value;
textFront.text = t;

var draggerFront = new createjs.Container();
draggerFront.x = 160;
draggerFront.y = 130;
draggerFront.addChild(textVorne,tb);
stage.addChild(draggerFront);

draggerFront.on("pressmove",function(evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX ; // here I have no idea what to
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY ; // do when the dragger reaches
    draggerFront.mouseMoveOutside = false; // boundary
    stage.update();  
});

stage.update();
```

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I repurposed your example so it works in jsfiddle.net, but I don't know if it is what you had in mind.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/xrqatyLs

If you are trying to drag the text, and constrain it to the box, here are the steps I took:

1. The box and text should live in the same place (both on stage)
2. Add the drag code to the text instead
3. You had the drag event set up right, you just have to constrain the position to be within the bounds. I used `Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val))` to do this.

Here is a modified example that works. This version constrains the text's "position" to the box. This means it will draw outside the box on the bottom and right.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/xrqatyLs/1/

To constrain the whole thing, subtract the text size from the "min" position.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/xrqatyLs/2/

```
textFront.on("pressmove",function(evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.x = Math.max(bounds.x, Math.min(bounds.x+bounds.width-textBounds.width, evt.stageX)); 
    evt.currentTarget.y = Math.max(bounds.y, Math.min(bounds.y+bounds.height-textBounds.height, evt.stageY)); 
    stage.update();  
});
```

A few additional things I would do to make in nicer:

1. Store the mouse offset when you first press, and subtract that value from the mouse position when you move. This will make the item drag from where you press it, instead of snapping to the top left
2. Add a hitArea shape onto the Text (which is the size of the textBounds) so you don't have to press the actual filled pixels of the text
3. Also consider the `textBounds.x/y` so you can use other text alignment modes. This demo assumes the text is drawing from the top/left.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Great examples to learn with, making the transition from Flash to CreateJS even easier. I still can't vote here, thus the comment. Thanks.

Comment: How to make it work when there is rotation or scaling, If the text is rotoated, i.e. `textFront.rotation = 90;` - it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer. For info, to solve additional point 1 retrieve the point the target was selected in a mousedown event and set as the transform point:

```
textFront.on("mousedown", function(e) {
    var localToTrack = e.currentTarget.globalToLocal(e.stageX, e.stageY);
    e.currentTarget.regX = localToTrack.x;
    e.currentTarget.regY = localToTrack.y;
});
```

Then in the pressmove event just take this transform point into account when checking the max/min bounds:

```
textFront.on("pressmove",function(evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.x = Math.max(bounds.x + evt.currentTarget.regX,
      Math.min(bounds.x + bounds.width - textBounds.width + evt.currentTarget.regX, evt.stageX));

    evt.currentTarget.y = Math.max(bounds.y + evt.currentTarget.regY, 
    Math.min(bounds.y + bounds.height - textBounds.height + evt.currentTarget.regY, evt.stageY));

    stage.update();
});
```

The text will now drag from where the mouse was clicked to give a smoother interaction. https://jsfiddle.net/poc275/uabLpomh/

Comment: Note that you can use `localX` and `localY`, instead of calculating them yourself: `e.currentTarget.regX = e.localX;`